# How to copy a link from markdown preview? Mouse right-click, Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Ins don't work. (copy doesn't work for any text in the preview?)

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown, copy-paste, preview

A markdown file is opened under *IntelliJ* and from its preview if I do a left click on a link, it will follow it and open it the default browser.

But for my current work, it's not what I'm willing to do.
I need to copy its underlying URL to open it on another browser of my choice, that isn't the default one.

But whatever I attempt:

1. Right-clicking on the link with the mouse
2. Attempt to copy it by selecting its text and doing `Ctrl-C` or `Ctrl-Ins`

the underlying URL of that link isn't copied and I cannot paste it.
Of course, I can enter the `.md` definition and select that URL part that is between parenthesis, but it's not convenient.

```markdown
* [COG 2021 : https://www.insee.fr/fr/information/5057840](https://www.insee.fr/fr/information/5057840)
```

And furthermore, I cannot copy any text content from that preview...

Is there a way to make *IntelliJ* preview window of a markdown file gaining the expected ability of copying to the clipboard ?

[image]

Comment: You can change the browser here: https://i.imgur.com/odED1yg.png

Answer (score -1):

Use markdown editor for this. For example Typora.

Comment: I'm running IntelliJ, not another editor. Don't change the subject please.